# How can i get the viewport height of my modal in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ng-zorro-antd

i would like to know if there is a possibility to get the viewport height of my ng boostrap modal in my Angular app.
Here is what i have:

- A modal with a css styling like this:

```css
.modal-xxl {
  width: 95% !important;
  max-height: 90% !important;
  max-width: 95% !important;
  height: 90% !important;

  .component-host-scrollable {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

- Inside the modal i have a ng zorro table which i need to be scrollable
- I want to change the scrollable height based on this calculation: `calc(100vh - 221,09px)` so that if i resize the screen the scroll height resizes as well

---

- I do not know how to get that `100vh` inside the html file.
- Right now the `nzScroll` property of ngzorro table only takes a number in px.
  I tried doing this: `viewHeight = window.innerHeight` on my ts component and then putting it into the html like so:
  `[nzScroll]="{ y: ' {{viewHeight}}px' }"` but it doesn't work ( i can't even scroll the table).
  If anyone can help i will thank him forever ahaha!!!

Comment: please add some demo code of stackblitz.com so that people can play around with ngZorro and find out what can we do in your example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so my problem was that this:

```html
[nzScroll]="{ y: 'calc(100vh - 276.09px)'}"
```

Didn't work because of the point `.` in the calculation.

So then i changed it to:

```html
[nzScroll]="{ y: 'calc(100vh - 276px)'}"
```

And now works just fine.
If anyone was wondering how i got that `276px` i basically did a sum of all the modal elements that were of fixed size like:

- Modal header: `69px`
- Modal Footer: `65px`
- And then the table height which was: `142px`

Therefore now if i decide to resize the window, the table scrollbar is going to resize as well.

Here is the before:

[image: Table before]

And that is the after:

[image: Table after]

As you can see if i increase the size of the table the table doesn't overflow the modal causing him to enable the scroll bar, it just resizes itself staying within the modal boundries.